# Как в С++ заполнить двухмерный массив объектов через цикл?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, циклы, конструктор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В строке 17 он ругается на отсутствие конструктора по умолчанию.
В строке 21 ругается на некорректную инициализацию object[i][j]= A(32,56);
Вопрос как правильно через цикл заполнить двухмерный массив объектов, чтобы вызывался конструктор с параметрами?

Comment: код приводите в виде текста, а не картинки

Comment: Это сделать невозможно, так как инициализация происходит на строке `A object[5][5];`. И вообще используйте vector

Comment: а точнее вектор пар :) vector<pair<int, int>>(n);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите в конструкторе

```
A(int a = 0, int b = 0):x(a)....
```

и не мучайтесь (просто создаем конструктор по умолчанию с параметрами 0,0).

Все прочие автоматически генерируемые компилятором конструкторы и операторы присвоения вполне пригодны для такого простого типа.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, сделать с помощью вектора.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  A(int a, int b): x(a), y(b) {}
  void get_value() {std::cout << x << ' ' << y; }

};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<A>> object;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
      object[i].push_back(A(i, j));
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```